# Is there any way to spawn the first local player and then the remote player photon fusion

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, multiplayer, photon

I am currently developing a multiplayer game using Photon Fusion. One feature I would like to implement is the sequential spawning of players, with the local player spawning first, and the remote player spawning afterwards. However, I am experiencing problems with achieving this desired order.

Currently, when a game session starts, both local and remote players seem to spawn in a seemingly random order, rather than the specific sequence I am targeting. This random spawning disrupts the game flow as I have implemented some features that rely on the local player being spawned first.

Specifically, my implementation involves a script where the local player is supposed to be spawned as soon as the connection to the Photon network is established. The remote player should be spawned only after the local player is successfully created.

Unfortunately, the script does not seem to work as intended, and the remote player occasionally spawns before the local player. This seems to be a synchronization issue between local and remote clients, but I have not been able to find a solution that ensures the correct order of player spawning.

I'm looking for any guidance or suggestions on how I can modify my Photon Fusion setup to ensure that the local player always spawns before the remote player. Does Photon Fusion provide any built-in functionality or settings that can help control the order of player spawning?

I have already tried various methods such as manipulating the 'OnConnectedToMaster' and 'OnJoinedRoom' callbacks but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: in general: What is this implementation you have that depends so much on the order?

Comment: The term local player refers to any player/client relative to themselves.  Are you instead referring to the host?

Comment: ye like the host joined and the local player is who has input authority.